# If$ p \in B(H)$ is a projection, then $r \in A'$ if and only if the closed vector subspace $p(H)$ of $H$ is invariant for $A$.

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

In the proof of the theorem $4.1.12$ on the page $120$ in Murphy, he uses a central remark that:

If $p$ is a projection in $B(H)$ , then $p$ belong to $A'$ if and only if the closed  vector subspace $p(H)$ of $H$ is invariant for $A$.

Here $A$ is a $C^*$-algebra acting on $H$.
Would you help me to prove the converse: if the closed  vector subspace $p(H)$ of $H$ is invariant for $A$ then $p$ belong to $A'$.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is A? is a subspace?

Comment: $A$ is a non-zero $C^*$-algebra acting on $H$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $W = p(H)$, then for any $T \in A, T(W) \subset W$. Hence,
$$
pTp = Tp
$$
Since $A$ is a $\ast$-algebra, $W$ is invariant under $T^{\ast}$ and hence $W^{\perp}$ is invariant under $T$. Thus,
$$
(1-p)T(1-p) = Tp \Rightarrow pTp = pT
$$
Hence, $pT = Tp$.

Comment: Thank you very much! for your smart answer

Comment: I feel you are making it unnecessarily complicated: from $pT^*p=T^*p$ you get $pTp=pT$ directly by taking adjoints. The assertion "W invariant under $T^*$ implies $W^\perp$ invariant under $T$" is basically what needs to be proven.